# Setting up Vimeo SDK in iOS

Tags: vimeo-ios

Trying to incorporate [Vimeo SDK from github](https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking) into my iOS project. 
Xcode 7.3.1

I have cocoa pods installed and my TestVimeo1 project setup but when I attempt target VIMNetworking, AFNetworking and VIMObjectMapper I must not be going about this correct.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/xcodebuild/_buildoutput/TestVimeo1-fktedyrxeulxmicndbpgghnbdjtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/xcodebuild/_buildoutput/TestVimeo1-fktedyrxeulxmicndbpgghnbdjtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VIMNetworking'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxxxx/xcodebuild/_buildoutput/TestVimeo1-fktedyrxeulxmicndbpgghnbdjtn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VIMObjectMapper'
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can't find the output directories. Where am I going wrong with setting up the target builds for these git submodules? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure those 3 libraries are actually copied over?
Check your target settings under "Link Binary With Libraries" ?

Comment: Did you actually do: `$ pod install` in your project directory?